# Graph of the same function represented differently?!

Tags: analysis, graphing-functions

I'm taking pre-calculus classes - learning about functions, limits and that stuff right now - and I came to $y = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$.
Google represents it like this:
[Google_graph_of_$y = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1BqQ.png)

But in Microsoft Mathematics it looks completely different:
[Microsoft_Mathematics_graph_of_$y = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSC1s.png)

Simply: WHY?

Comment: The second curve is $y=1/x$ and is not $sin(1/x)$. Make sure you type the parenthesis correctly.

Comment: Ahh... Beginners mistake! :S
Thank you @NoChance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second curve is $y=1/x$ and is not $sin(1/x)$. Make sure you type the parenthesis correctly.